# Java XML @ output SAX

Tags: java, xml, sax

i am really a bit clueless.I use JAXB for reading values out of xml files,and also SAX parser,where the same problem occurs.It seems to be code-independent,but i am really with no idea.
While trying to read attributes out of XML files,and i also copied several code examples out of the net---i want them to be shown after serializing them and also before.
Likle for example i have a xml File with book elements in it.And printing them out.
Instead of the expected values like : author=xxx  , price =yyy etc i just get an output like:

packagename.Book@1fbc355
packename.Book@1d532ae      when i want to let me show the values.

This Problem i not only have with the complete copied examples ,but also with my own code,so it must be a code-independent problem,but i have no clue what it could be.
So i get no output in Form of parsing results ,but just this kind of stuff.
I have really no idea.Perhaps somebody has an idea what i am generally doing wrong.I would be very thankful(serveral days of trying with no result)

Answer (score 1):

Java calls the `.toString()` method of an object when printing an object that isn't a string. The base Object class by default implements `.toString()` as [returning a string with class name and the hexadecimal representation of the hashCode() of the object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29). So if you want the object to be printed differently, you'll need to implement a custom `.toString()` method